# How to avoid writing same code over again in UIViewController in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, swift5

I have the following piece of code that I write in every UIViewController:

```
var navBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
    navBar?.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```

I don't want to write these in every `UIViewController` that I create. I am lazy and I don't want to repeat myself. I can't add it in `extension`. So what can I do to not have to write this piece of code when I create `UIViewController`?

Comment: Can't you just extract this code into a function, passing the nav controller as a param?

Comment: Also, the key type is already known to be `NSAttributedString.Key`, so you could just write: `[.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Use a base UIViewController such as BaseViewController and put this code inside viewDidLoad and replace UIViewController with BaseViewController.

2.You may not want to do anything to UIViewController.Then,you may come across the term AOP.for example Java use AOP a lot.

You can use AOP framework like Aspects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the default implementation protocol in this case.

Create default implementation protocol:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol TitleSetupable: AnyObject {
    func setupTitle()
}

extension TitleSetupable where Self: UIViewController {
    func setupTitle() {
        var navBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
        navBar?.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    }
}
```

Use in your ViewController:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, TitleSetupable {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupTitle()
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not valid to call a function in a class declaration like that. This isn't Ruby, for better or worse.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica yes. i add viewDidLoad.

Comment: I know that we can use protocol and/or extension to minimize redundancy, but I was asking this question hoping that someone has different answers.